# Counting instances of maxima in a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a meteorologist learning Pandas and had a problem that has me stumped. Hopefully someone can help. I have a CSV file of hourly temperatures for a year (four columns: month, day, hour, temperature). What I'm trying to find is how many times the high was at a particular time. In other words, how many times was the highest temperature for the day reported at 3pm, 4pm, etc.? I tried to use groupby, but haven't gotten anywhere. Any ideas? A sample of the data is shown below.

[Sample data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVbgI.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: Please add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a minimal reproducible example for explicitness, however based on your description you could use:

```
# max temperature of the day
MAX = df.groupby(['month', 'day'])['temperature'].transform('max')

# count the hours matching the max
df['temperature'].eq(MAX).groupby(df['hour']).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks. I don’t know how to include an image, but the columns in my data set are month (1-12), day (1-31), hour (0-23, 0 corresponding to midnight local time), and the temperature.

Comment: Have you tested the solution?

Comment: Not yet. I haven’t been to the office yet today. I plan on going in later today.

Comment: @David you're welcome, when you have a minute please update your question with a tiny example of the data. This will help future readers.

Comment: I’ll be in my office tonight and I’ll upload something then